# What does YII use for notices, warnings etc?

Tags: yii

I have a form that works perfectly. If filled in and validation passes, it takes you to another page which is also a form. However, when the user goes to this form, I want to display a "warning" at the top. I know drupal has [drupal_set_message function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6), but what does YII have to accomplish something similar?

Comment: can't believe this was closed. what a joke...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii uses something like

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('notice', 'This is your notice');
```

In the view you need to add something like this then:

```
foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
}
```

More info can be found here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/

Comment: As a follow up, you don't maybe know of a quick way to include all flash messages to be displayed immediately on the next page? I.e. Regardless of where I redirect?

Comment: A simple way to do that would be to define that piece of code in the views/layout/main file